# Which coroutine dispatcher to inject when testing a Kotlin console

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a back-end springboot Kotlin app that has some simple coroutine code for parallel IO operations. It looks something like this

```
@Service
class AccountService(
    private val client: ApiClient
    private val coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) {

  fun getAccount(): AccountDTO {

    return runBlocking(coroutineDispatcher) {
      val foo = async {
        client.getFoo() //some long operation
      }

      val bar = async {
        client.getBar() //some other operation
      }

      AccountDTO(foo.await(), bar.await())
    }
  }
}
```

Now in production I can inject let's say a `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher and everything works fine. However when testing I don't want multithreading. I want to inject `Dispatcher.Main` but it's meant for android apps. Alternatively I'd like to inject nothing and let the scope inherit from the parent and run on the main thread, the way `runBlocking{}` works without any arguments. But I can't figure out how to do that. Should I be using `Dispatchers.Unconfined`? From what I understand it will stay on the main thread unless I spin up another thread myself explicitly.

What's the standard practice here?

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively I'd like to inject nothing and let the scope inherit from the parent and run on the main thread, the way runBlocking{} works without any arguments. But I can't figure out how to do that

If you have control over `getAccount()` here, you should make this one `suspend` and avoid `runBlocking` at this level. If you're just introducing coroutines in the project, it's of course fine like this as a first step, but I would encourage you to keep going up the call stack soon. This way you'll benefit from context inheritance and avoid blocking threads from other coroutines if they decide to call your service.

Now, you could use `kotlinx-coroutines-test` for your tests, they provide test dispatchers that you can use, which even allow you to control virtual time and test timeouts etc. Note, however, that due to the virtual time, you cannot use this kind of dispatcher for code that calls an actual system that's not part of virtual time (like some external service, or just a piece of code using a hardcoded non-test dispatcher).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. There isn't really anywhere further to go up the stack, `getAccount()` is called by a REST controller.
I did come across `kotlinx-coroutines-test` previously, but my understanding is that it's still experimental and not advised to be used in stable code.

Comment: @Egor where did you see that it was experimental? Also, the Spring controllers actually can support `suspend` handlers in WebFlux mode, which allows for a fully non-blocking request handling. If you use `runBlocking` right beneath the controller, you still have 1 thread per request

Comment: here https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/
Says "This API is experimental ... it is not advised to use the API in stable code before it leaves experimental due to possible breaking changes."

Comment: Oh right. Somehow I had missed this. That said, it's about test code, so I don't think it's too much of an issue to use experimental functions. At worst you have to rewrite some of the tests when upgrading the library